# How to check for wins in a tic-tac-toe game?

Tags: python, any

My task is to make a tic-tac-toe game. Grid consists of 3 rows. I developed core game play, the thing works, but for some reason I can't check for wins. I have `if any(wins_x)` and `if any(wins_o)` at the end of the turns.

```
row1 = ['-', '-', '-']
row2 = ['-', '-', '-']
row3 = ['-', '-', '-']
table = [row1, row2, row3]

wins_x = [(row1[0] == 'x' and row2[1] == 'x' and row3[2] == 'x'),
          (row3[0] == 'x' and row2[1] == 'x' and row1[2] == 'x'),
          (row1 == ['x', 'x', 'x']),
          (row2 == ['x', 'x', 'x']),
          (row3 == ['x', 'x', 'x']),
          (row1[0] == 'x' and row2[0] == 'x' and row3[0] == 'x'),
          (row1[1] == 'x' and row2[1] == 'x' and row3[1] == 'x'),
          (row1[2] == 'x' and row2[2] == 'x' and row3[2] == 'x')]

wins_o = [(row1[0] == 'o' and row2[1] == 'o' and row3[2] == 'o'),
          (row3[0] == 'o' and row2[1] == 'o' and row1[2] == 'o'),
          (row1 == ['o', 'o', 'o']),
          (row2 == ['o', 'o', 'o']),
          (row3 == ['o', 'o', 'o']),
          (row1[0] == 'o' and row2[0] == 'o' and row3[0] == 'o'),
          (row1[1] == 'o' and row2[1] == 'o' and row3[1] == 'o'),
          (row1[2] == 'o' and row2[2] == 'o' and row3[2] == 'o')]
```

Comment: Tried using the debugger?

Comment: The values that end up in `wins_x` and `wins_o` are determine when the lists are created, so you would need to put them into a function that created them and checked their values every time it was called.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
def wincheck(table):
  for x in range(0,len(table)):
    if len([y for y in table[x] if y=="x"])==len(table):
      print(f"win x row {x+1}")
    elif len([y for y in table[x] if y=="o"])==len(table):
      print(f"win o row {x+1}")
  for x in range(0,len(table)):
    if len([y for y in table if y[x]=="x"])==len(table):
      print(f"win x Column {x+1}")
    elif len([y for y in table if y[x]=="o"])==len(table):
      print(f"win o Column {x+1}")
  if len([y for y in range(0,len(table)) if table[y][len(table)-1-y] =="x" ])==len(table) or len([y for y in range(0,len(table)) if table[y][y] =="x" ])==len(table):
    print("diagonal win x")
  elif len([y for y in range(0,len(table)) if table[y][len(table)-1-y] =="o" ])==len(table) or len([y for y in range(0,len(table)) if table[y][y] =="o" ])==len(table):
    print("diagonal win o")
wincheck(table)
```

It should work regardless of size, but I definetly know it works for 3x3. This function basically checks each row, column and diagonal to see if the `"o"` or `"x"` is in it.

Comment: No problem. Mark it as an answer if you think it is deserving.